# How to recreate sam/emulation-java11 image using openjdk11

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-serverless

Wanted to re-create sam/emulation-java11 to make it work within enterprise as images from outside is not allowed, any reference from where source code of this docker image can be pulled.

https://gallery.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-java11

Image Reference - https://gallery.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-java11

Purpose - AWS Step Functions and AWS Lambda integration to run on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to peek under the hood with `docker image history`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_history/

It should show you every step without the original `FROM` from Dockerfile.